# Computer cannot ping to another computer on a different network

Tags: vlan

So my problem starts with a PC that has IP address 192.168.7.1 that cannot ping a PC with IP address 192.168.6.1. Both get their IP addresses from a Cisco router via DHCP. The router has IP address 192.168.7.10 on Fa0/0 and 192.168.6.10 on Fa0/1.

The first switch has a VLAN interface 65 with IP address 192.168.7.40 while the second switch has a VLAN interface 55 with IP address 192.168.6.40.

The first switch has another VLAN interface (99) with IP address 192.168.30.1. This VLAN is trunked to the second switch (192.168.30.2). The router has the spanning tree protocol up.

So is it because of VLAN 99 IP address that the PCs cannot ping each other?

[image: Network topology]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Network Engineering. Please [edit] your question and add relevant configurations for the switches and the router.

Comment: VLAN 55 and VLAN 65 have the same address in your drawing.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the configuration text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`). Be sure to include the full configurations of all the network devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

PC1 to ping host not in his lan ( lan for pc1 is 192.168.7.0/x) will send icmp request to default gateway - 192.168.7.10 Then router must forward to lan2. PC2's firewall must be configured to allow incoming connections from not local lan and router must be configured to allow forwarding between lan1 and lan2.

Comment: well that was a really bad mistake on my part... vlan 65 has a ip address of 192.168.6.40... my bad